# How do I append a Redirect to a VoiceResponse in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: twilio

Using Twilio 5.16
Asp.Net Core 2.1.1

I have a code sample that I am trying to port to asp.net **core** from asp.net mvc
I'm having a problem working out what to use for the line:

```
response.Redirect(Url.ActionUri("ShortWelcome", "IVR"));
```

because there is no longer an 'ActionUri' method on Url.

My Controller Action:

```
using Twilio.AspNet.Core;
using Twilio.TwiML;
using Twilio.TwiML.Voice;

namespace IVRPhoneTree.Core.Web.Controllers
{
    public abstract class ControllerBase : TwilioController
    {
        public TwiMLResult RedirectWelcome()
        {
            var response = new VoiceResponse();
            response.Say("Returning to the main menu ", Say.VoiceEnum.PollyBrian, 1, Say.LanguageEnum.EnAu);
            response.Redirect(Url.ActionUri("Welcome", "IVR"));

            return TwiML(response);
        }



        public TwiMLResult RedirectBadPin()
        {
            var response = new VoiceResponse();
            response.Say("Sorry that pin is not correct. Returning you to the main menu. ",
                Say.VoiceEnum.PollyBrian, 1, Say.LanguageEnum.EnAu);
            response.Redirect(Url.ActionUri("ShortWelcome", "IVR"));

            return TwiML(response);
        }


    }
}
```

TIA

Comment: would it be something like: response.Redirect(new Uri("../IVR/ShortWelcome"),HttpMethod.Get); ?

Answer (score 0):

i ended up using aspnet core built in DI

so in start-up ConfigureServices:

```
services
            .AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>()
            .AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(x => x
                .GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>()
                .GetUrlHelper(x.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext));
```

Then in Controller ctr:

```
 private readonly IUrlHelper _urlHelper;
  public IVRController(IUrlHelper urlHelper)
  {
      _urlHelper = urlHelper;
  }
```

which allowed me to:

```
 public TwiMLResult RedirectBadPin()
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        response.Say("Sorry that pin is not correct. Returning you to the main menu. ",
            Say.VoiceEnum.PollyBrian, 1, Say.LanguageEnum.EnAu);

        string path = _urlHelper.Action("ShortWelcome", "IVR");

        response.Redirect(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute), HttpMethod.Get);   

        return TwiML(response);
    }
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and your solution is throwing System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'